# How can you use a page for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, get-posts

I have a CPT from a theme I bought called "[Services](http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/bbds/services/)" and it uses the `index.php` file. I have also created a page called "/services", but the CPT is outputting a page to override it.

I tried creating both a `archive-services.php` and `single-services.php` page with:

```
$args = array(
    'p' => 795
);
$custom_query = new WP_query( $args );

if( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
   $custom_query->the_post();
   the_title();
   the_excerpt();
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
wp_reset_query();

// With get_post()

$get_content = get_post( 795 );
setup_postdata( $get_content );
the_title();
the_excerpt();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

In the attempt to pull the page data and output it in the theme file, but even with this, and I don't even know if that's correct, the Services page uses `index.php`.

I just want my page to take over.

Comment: visit the link hope it will help you to figure out your problem.   
https://pippinsplugins.com/querying-custom-post-types-in-your-theme-templates/  . You can also visit https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/ link

Comment: Is the CPT named `services`, or is it something else, like `service` or `prefix_service`? Your template files need to use the exact post type name as defined in the [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) call that creates the post type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find out your exact CPT name (is it just services?)  and that will be the archive-services.php and single-services.php.

Those need to be either in your theme folder or if you're using a child theme (you should be)  these files will be in your child theme folder.

show us the code to create your CPT from theme code to create the CPT and that will give us more info.